# Erro CS1503 visual Studio C# "não é possivel converter para System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c++, visual-studio

Estou usando o Guna framework para uma aplicação Desktop
ao tentar usar o textbox do framework e implementar o evento KeyPress
apresenta o seguinte erro : **Erro  CS1503  Argumento 2: não é possível converter de "Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2TextBox" para "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox"   GUI C:\newprojet\GunaManager\GUI\frm_cad_pessoa.cs**[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei a solução indicada mais não deu certo

```
private void txtCep_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.KeyChar != (char)8)
           {

               Campo edit = Campo.CEP;
               Formatar(edit, txtCep2);

           }
       }
```

Comment: Tem que pegar o texto do objeto com `Text`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0.

Comment: Seu metodo Formatar esta esperando um objeto do tipo TextBox, e seu txtCep2 é do tipo Guna2TextBox.

Comment: @MarcosJunior Como faço para ele aceitar o tipo Guna2TextBox ?

Comment: você não consegue alterar o parametro do metodo Formatar?

Comment: na teoria o Guna2TextBox tem as mesmas propriedades que o TextBox

Comment: @MarcosJunior na verdade não sei como fazer.

Comment: Edita a pergunta colocando o método Formatar completo